# Team City Build and Octopus deploy

Tags: teamcity, octopus-deploy

Team city is often used for building and then use Octopus for deploy. I wonder if I can use a successful octopus deploy to trigger a team city build? If it is possible, how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an integration between [Octopus Subscriptions](https://octopus.com/blog/subscriptions) (basically webhooks) to call off to TeamCity's API, but you'd have to create that manually, there's no built-in "connectors".

I'd question why you want to do this though?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add a script step at the end of your deployment which would call the TeamCity URL to trigger a build.

There appears that there is also a community step in the library for doing a HTTP GET or HTTP POST.

Ensure you set the Run Condition to Success so that it will only be triggered when the full deployment has been completed.